# How to connect any server using ssh in Cypress.io to run a command?

Tags: javascript, ssh, server, cypress

I know that this probably is not the best way to do this. I read the question with the same title here, but it not solve my problem.

The question is: I have a server that only will achieve a result that I wanna if I run a command line in the server. So I wanna write a test to check the state of one page before and after I run that command. How I do that?

I tried to use the simple-ssh package, but I keep getting this error while trying to read the ssh key file:

`fs.readFileSync is not a function`

Actually my code looks like this:

```js
import * as fs from 'fs';

let sshConfig = Cypress.config('ssh')
sshConfig.key = fs.readFileSync('path/to/key/file')
let SSH = require('simple-ssh');

Cypress.Commands.add('teste', () => {
    let ssh = new SSH(sshConfig)

    ssh.exec('echo', {
        args: ['$PATH'],
        out: function(stdout) {
            console.log(stdout);
        }
    }).start();
})
```

Other possibility's are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Fody mentioned, there are node.js functions present inside `simple-ssh` so a task is needed.

This is the basic configuration.

It's a direct translation of what you have, but you would want to return something from the task. As it is, the `console.log()` goes to the terminal console not the browser console.

**cypress.config.js**

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')
const fs = require('fs')
const SSH = require('simple-ssh');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('task', {
        ssh() {
          const sshConfig = config.ssh
          sshConfig.key = fs.readFileSync('path/to/key/file')
 
          const ssh = new SSH(sshConfig)      
          ssh.exec('echo', {
            args: ['$PATH'],
            out: function(stdout) {
              console.log(stdout);
            }
          }).start();

          return null
        },
      })
    }
  }
})
```

**test**

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('ssh', () => {
  cy.task('ssh')
})

cy.ssh()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it with `cy.readFile()`.

```js
const SSH = require('simple-ssh');

Cypress.Commands.add('testSSH', () => {

  cy.readFile('path/to/key/file').then(key
    const sshConfig = Cypress.config('ssh')
    sshConfig.key = key

    const ssh = new SSH(sshConfig)
    ssh.exec('echo', {
      args: ['$PATH'],
      out: function(stdout) {
        console.log(stdout);
      }
    }).start()
  })
})
```

The problem is `fs` is a node.js library, and it cannot be used in the browser.

But you may find the same thing applies to `simple-ssh`, If so, you will have to shift the code into a [task](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task) where you can use any node.js functions.